# StyleableProperty: how to change value programatically at runtime?

Tags: java, css, javafx

My use-case:

- a custom property on a control that should be configurable via css
- the property must be changeable at runtime
- for a given instance of the control, the programmatic change must not be reverted on re-applying the css

A custom [StyleableProperty](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/StyleableProperty.html) looks like a perfect match to implement the requirement. Below is an example that implements (taken without change from the class javadoc of [StyleablePropertyFactory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/StyleablePropertyFactory.html)).

All is fine except for the last requirement: on applyCss, the default value from the stylesheet is reapplied. To reproduce:

- run the example, note that the initial "selected" state (the checkbox' selected is bound it) of the MyButton is true
- click the custom button, note that the "selected" doesn't change to false (though the actionHandler changes it)
- click on the second ("toggle") button, note that the selected state of the custom button changes to false
- hover the mouse over the custom button, note that the selected state falls back to true

The reason for falling back to true (the value set via style), can be traced to  applyCss which happens on state changes ... which is understandable and might be the correct thingy-to-do most of the times, but not in my context.

So the questions:

- am I on the right track with using StyleableProperty?
- if so, how to tweak such that it's not re-apply after a manual change has happened?
- if not, what else to do?
- or maybe asking the wrong questions altogether: maybe properties which are settable via css are not meant to be (permanently) changed by code?

The example:

```
public class StyleableButtonDriver extends Application {

    /**
     * example code from class doc of StyleablePropertyFactory.
     */
    private static class MyButton extends Button {

        private static final StyleablePropertyFactory<MyButton> FACTORY 
            = new StyleablePropertyFactory<>(Button.getClassCssMetaData());

        MyButton(String labelText) {
            super(labelText);
            getStyleClass().add("my-button");
            setStyle("-my-selected: true");
        }

        // Typical JavaFX property implementation
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> selectedProperty() { return (ObservableValue<Boolean>)selected; }
        public final boolean isSelected() { return selected.getValue(); }
        public final void setSelected(boolean isSelected) { selected.setValue(isSelected); }

        // StyleableProperty implementation reduced to one line
        private final StyleableProperty<Boolean> selected =
             FACTORY.createStyleableBooleanProperty(
                    this, "selected", "-my-selected", s -> s.selected);

        @Override
        public List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getControlCssMetaData() {
            return FACTORY.getCssMetaData();
        }

        public static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getClassCssMetaData() {
            return FACTORY.getCssMetaData();
        }

    }
    private Parent createContent() {
        MyButton button = new MyButton("styleable button");
        button.setOnAction(e ->  {
            // does not work: reset on applyCss
            boolean isSelected = button.isSelected();
            button.setSelected(!isSelected);
        });

        CheckBox box = new CheckBox("button selected");
        box.selectedProperty().bind(button.selectedProperty());

        Button toggle = new Button("toggle button");
        toggle.setOnAction(e -> {
            boolean isSelected = button.isSelected();
            button.setSelected(!isSelected);
        });


        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(button);
        content.setBottom(new HBox(10, box, toggle));
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent(), 300, 200));
        //same behavior as setting the style directly
//        URL uri = getClass().getResource("xstyleable.css");
//        stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(uri.toExternalForm());
        // not useful: would have to override all
//        Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(uri.toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(StyleableButtonDriver.class.getName());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but since you need to override the default priority of the style origins (user agent stylesheet < programmatically assigned < css stylesheet < `Node.style` property), you cannot use `SyleablePropertyFactory` for creating this property. You need to create a `CssMetaData` object that indicates a property as non-setable, if the property was programatically assigned.

```
private static class MyButton extends Button {

    private static final List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> CLASS_CSS_METADATA;
    private static final CssMetaData<MyButton, Boolean> SELECTED;

    static {
        SELECTED = new CssMetaData<MyButton, Boolean>("-my-selected", StyleConverter.getBooleanConverter()) {

            @Override
            public boolean isSettable(MyButton styleable) {
                // not setable, if bound or set by user
                return styleable.selected.getStyleOrigin() != StyleOrigin.USER  && !styleable.selected.isBound();
            }

            @Override
            public StyleableProperty<Boolean> getStyleableProperty(MyButton styleable) {
                return styleable.selected;
            }

        };

        // copy list of button css metadata to list and add new metadata object
        List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> buttonData = Button.getClassCssMetaData();
        List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> mybuttonData = new ArrayList<>(buttonData.size()+1);
        mybuttonData.addAll(buttonData);
        mybuttonData.add(SELECTED);
        CLASS_CSS_METADATA = Collections.unmodifiableList(mybuttonData);
    }

    MyButton(String labelText) {
        super(labelText);
        getStyleClass().add("my-button");
        setStyle("-my-selected: true");
    }

    // Typical JavaFX property implementation
    public ObservableValue<Boolean> selectedProperty() { return selected; }
    public final boolean isSelected() { return selected.get(); }
    public final void setSelected(boolean isSelected) { selected.set(isSelected); }

    // StyleableProperty implementation reduced to one line
    private final SimpleStyleableBooleanProperty selected = new SimpleStyleableBooleanProperty(SELECTED, this, "selected");

    @Override
    public List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getControlCssMetaData() {
        return CLASS_CSS_METADATA;
    }

    public static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getClassCssMetaData() {
        return CLASS_CSS_METADATA;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks promising - will try tomorrow and come back, thanks :-)